# Echo statement makes new line every echo

Tags: php, echo

I have a basic php echo statment as belows which echos a thumnail 70*70 but it echos a new line everytime. Is there anyway to stop this?

```
echo "<div class='imageIcon'><a href='index.php?menu=GaleriaYVideo&catAll=$var_catergoryAll&image=".$var_showImageAll."'><img src=".$var_showImageIcnAll." ></a></div>";
```

Basically i want to echo all my thumbs so there on the same line.
Any help well appreciated!

Comment: How have you determined it echo's a newline? The code you show should not do that - to echo a newline, it must be explicitly outputted in the echo statement, and there are none in the example you show.

Answer (score 9):

You're wrapping your output in a block-level `div` element. Remove that, or set `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` and they will all be inline. Or float the elements and give them a width.

Comment: Or, if he insists on using `div`s, he could add `style="display:inline;"` to them.

Comment: I tried using the display:inlink-block but for some reason its making new line for every icon, here is all the CSS im using for that part:         .imageIconBar{
 text-align:left;
  height:110px;
    width:760px;
 overflow:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:#CCC;
 position:absolute;
}

Comment: @ScottRobertson Where did `.imageIconBar` come from? That's not in your code example above. I encouraged you to add `display:inline-block` to `<div class='imageIcon'>`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have width and height set to the class.

Set something like

```
.imageIcon {
width:70px;
height:70px;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `.imageIcon {display:inline;}` to your style

Answer (score 0):

It's not the echo that's causing the new line, it's the div element